# What are the new 2014 Festive Weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What are the new 2014 Festive Weapons? I can't seem to find any other information out there on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image] - Festive Chargin' Targe

[image] - Festive Shotgun

[image] - Festive Backburner

[image] - Festive Revolver

[image] - Festive Bonk! Atomic Punch

[image] - Festive SMG

[image] - Festive Bonesaw

All festive weapons have a chance to be unboxed in the Strange quality.